# Django Admin: making bulk admin actions with a class

Tags: django, django-admin

I've been trying to automate the creation of a series of admin actions in Django.

Basically I want to create the possibility to bulk change a status field on a Project object. The status field is a ForeignkeyField.

I thought making a Class like this would work:

```
class StatusAction(object):

    def __init__(self,status):
         self.status = status

    def make_action(self, modeladmin, request, queryset):
        self.queryset = queryset.update(status=self.status)

    make_action.short_description = "Change status to '%s' for selected projects" % status
```

and then declare the actions like :

```
actions = [StatusAction(s.id).make_action for s in Status.objects.all()]
```

I am encountering two problems:

- Only one action ends up in the Admin interface (the last declerated).
- the make_action.short_description attribute has class scope, so I can't make it specific for each instance. putting self.make_action.short_description in make_action doesn't work either.

I also tried doing this with a closure (function in a function). It solves the attribute of a function problem, but still only one action ends up in the admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the action functions should have different names:

```
def create_action(status):
    def action_func(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        print status
    action_func.__name__ = 'make_action_%d' % status.id
    action_func.short_description = "Change status to '%s' for selected projects" % status
    return action_func

actions = []
for s in Status.objects.all():
    actions.append(create_action(s))
```