# Django admin: action-select jquery/js check if checkbox was selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin

Django admin project, in change_list.html

Using jquery/js, I want to know if one or more of the action-select check-boxes were selected.
so i saw:

```
$(".action-select");
```

to get an array object of all the inputs,
but i do not know how to do the loop and get the value of each action-select- if that is the correct way to do that anyway? 
If there is a better way, i'll be happy to learn.

This is not a form/admin view question, i mean before any button was pressed, at the browser level, thanks

EDIT:
I was looking for something like this :

```
$(".action-select").each(function( i ) { if (this.checked) { console.log('asd'); do other stuff; }});
```

Final Edit:
So, to achieve my goal, I stopped the table db polls while one or more of the check-boxes are checked, this is what i needed :)

```
function resetTimeout() {
  var action_bool = false;
  $(".action-select").each(function(i) {
   if (this.checked) 
      action_bool = true;
    }
    );
  if (!action_bool) {
    $("#result_list").load(location.href+" #result_list*","");
      }

  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(resetTimeout,5000);
```

Comment: I think this is what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878894/django-admin-making-bulk-admin-actions-with-a-class

Comment: no- i mean on js /jquery

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?:

```
$(".action-select").each(function( i ) { 
    if (this.is(":checked")) {
        console.log('asd'); 
        do other stuff;
    }
);
```